# Не получается освобождать память

Tags: c++

Имеется функция:

```
void mem_init(char *mem_buf)
{
     mem_buf = new char[2<<20];
     memset(mem_buf,0,(2<<20));
}
```

На вход функции идет указатель, потом производится обработка (в данном случае заполняю нулями).

В главной функции вызываю ее, скажем, 100 раз:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        char *c;
        mem_init(c);
        delete[] c;
    }
```

После вызова `delete[]` память чудесным образом не освобождается (смотрю Диспетчером задач Windows). В чем подвох?

```
С уважением maxspb.
```

Comment: Диспетчер задач - далеко не самый лучший инструмент для отслеживания утечек. Если память систематически течет и обильно, то оно конечно поможет найти, но не в Вашем случае.

Используйте специальные инструменты. В линуксе я люблю использовать  valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался, нужно передавать ссылку на указатель в функцию:

```
void mem_init(char *&mem_buf)
{
     mem_buf = new char[2<<20];
     memset(mem_buf,0,(2<<20));
}
```